# Is there a way to trigger a function on FCM notification received in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to show a badge on app icon on iPhone when app receives a notification, so users can notice they received a notice if they see the app icon.

Following code does not work as expected as onMessageOpenedApp and checkForInitialMessage() will be triggered when user tapps notification, but not on notification arrives. How can I trigger setBadge() when iPhone receives notification?

I am using firebase_messaging 10.0.2 and flutter_app_badger.

```
// App is on background
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    setBadge();
});

// App is terminated
checkForInitialMessage() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    RemoteMessage initialMessage = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

    if (initialMessage != null) {
       setBadge();
    }
}
```

Comment: As CommonMind said, FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage() works OK on Android. However, it won't be triggered on iOS unfortunately. Apparently it is a flutter's bug. I tried "content_available" suggested below, but did not work:
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/6112

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to use `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage` to register a background message handler like so:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_backgroundMessageHandler);

static Future<dynamic> _backgroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  setBadge();
}
```

Here is the official documentation: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/#background-messages